# how to paint area in JAVA

Tags: java, paint

I have this code:

```
public void DoDraw(Graphics g, Main_Data M_D, int x, int y){
    if(x<0 || y<0 || x>50 || y>60){
        return;
    }
    else
    if(M_D.getPix()[x][y].p_c.isEmpty()){

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    }
    DoDraw(g ,M_D, x+1, y);
    DoDraw(g ,M_D, x, y+1);
    DoDraw(g ,M_D, x-1, y);
    DoDraw(g ,M_D, x, y-1);
    return;
}
```

This is my problem : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

where is mistake please??

Comment: Just by looking at the code, im pretty sure you're recursively calling DoDraw too many times with the method. Somewhere down the line, your `if(x<0 || y<0 || x>50 || y>60)` wont be triggered. At this point, the method cant stop calling itself. Could have been found with simple debugging /:

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in that you have "infinite" recursion. `DoDraw` calls itself in a way that never reaches the base case where the recursion terminates. It'll keep going back and forth between the same arguments until Java runs out of stack space and has to terminate.